# ¿por qué no funciona la validación de los productos (ramos) con el operador lógico | |?

Tags: javascript, funciones, validación, comparaciones, validationerror

Comunidad ¡los saludo! Acá tengo un problema de validación de productos ingresados por el usuario. El código anda de maravilla pero cuando intento hacer la validación de los tipos de ramos en la función ingreseRamo( ), lo cual está comentado en el código, no lo toma... no sé si con .normalize se podrá solucionar pero intenté hacerlo y no pude. Tal vez sea algo que no logro visualizar o tal vez deba realizar otro tipo de comparación o validación, quizás utilizar números en vez de strings... Agradezco la ayuda

```
const Stock = {
  rosas: 100,
  azucenas: 50,
  helechos: 80,
  hojas: 30,
}

class Ramos {
  constructor(nombre, precio, Contenido) {
    this.nombre = nombre
    this.precio = precio
    this.contenido = Contenido
  }
}
class Contenido {
  constructor(rosas, azucenas, helechos, hojas) {
    this.rosas = rosas
    this.azucenas = azucenas
    this.helechos = helechos
    this.hojas = hojas
  }
  modificarStock() {
    Stock.rosas -= this.rosas
    Stock.azucenas -= this.azucenas
    Stock.helechos -= this.helechos
    Stock.hojas -= this.hojas
  }
}

const contenidoSimple = new Contenido(6, 0, 2, 1)
const contenidoExtra = new Contenido(12, 3, 4, 2)
const contenidoElegante = new Contenido(0, 6, 3, 2)
const contenidoFresco = new Contenido(3, 3, 2, 1)

const Simple = new Ramos('Simple', 500, contenidoSimple)
const Extra = new Ramos('Extra', 1000, contenidoExtra)
const Elegante = new Ramos('Elegante', 1300, contenidoElegante)
const Fresco = new Ramos('Fresco', 800, contenidoFresco)

let ramoElegido = ''
function ingreseRamo() {
  ramoElegido = prompt(
    'Ingrese el ramo que desea comprar.(Simple, Extra, Elegante o Fresco)',
  ).toLowerCase()

  /*  while (
    ramoElegido !== 'fresco' ||
    ramoElegido !== 'extra' ||
    ramoElegido !== 'elegante' ||
    ramoElegido !== 'simple'
  ) {
    ramoElegido = prompt(
      'Ingrese el nombre de un ramo válido.(Simple, Extra, Elegante o Fresco)',
    )
  } */

  return ramoElegido
}
ingreseRamo()
console.log(ramoElegido)

contenidoSimple.modificarStock(ramoElegido)
console.log(Stock)
```

Comment: De las cuatro expresiones "!==", en un momento dado como mucho solo una será "false", las otras serán "true". Si ramoElegido == 'fresco', entonces ramoElegido !== 'extra'...

Comment: Fijate en principio, no uses el nombre de la Clase para asignar el valor a la propiedad this.contenido y en lugar de guardar los ramos en variables independientes, intenta hacer un Array o un objeto que contenga los elementos a buscar, luego con un Find o un Filter, o incluiso un Includes, podes elegir tu ramo y re preguntar si no se ingresa uno adecuado.

Comment: Igualmente, por lo que entiendo, tu comparación deberia ser con && y no con || pues con que sea distinta del primero, siempre sera verdadera.